# Ternary If statement for mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, ternary-operator

How can I add more ternary if-statements for my $sql variable? It outputs blank when I try to add more:

Working:

```
$sql = "SELECT r.title,r.author,r.summary,r.posted_on,r.review_url,r.rating 
        FROM reviews r 
        LEFT JOIN websites w 
        ON w.id=r.website_id 
        WHERE w.rooftop_id=$rooftop_id
        AND review_site_id IN ($sites)
        AND rating >= $star_threshold
        AND review_status_id=2
        " . ($pagination == 1 ? " LIMIT $offset, $review_limit " : "");
```

Not working:

```
$sql = "SELECT r.title,r.author,r.summary,r.posted_on,r.review_url,r.rating 
        FROM reviews r 
        LEFT JOIN websites w 
        ON w.id=r.website_id 
        WHERE w.rooftop_id=$rooftop_id
        AND review_site_id IN ($sites)
        AND rating >= $star_threshold
        AND review_status_id=2
        " . ($pagination == 1 ? " LIMIT $offset, $review_limit " : "")
        " . ($rating_filter == 1 ? " ORDER BY r.rating " : "");
```

Comment: look at your quotes. they are wrong.

Comment: Turn your error reporting on! Look for `error_reporting` and `display_errors` in your `php.ini`.

Answer (score 2):

There was a typo in your query, try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT r.title,r.author,r.summary,r.posted_on,r.review_url,r.rating 
        FROM reviews r 
        LEFT JOIN websites w 
        ON w.id=r.website_id 
        WHERE w.rooftop_id=$rooftop_id
        AND review_site_id IN ($sites)
        AND rating >= $star_threshold
        AND review_status_id=2
        " . ($pagination == 1 ? " LIMIT $offset, $review_limit " : "")
        . ($rating_filter == 1 ? " ORDER BY r.rating " : "");
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of MySQL, the `LIMIT` clause cannot precede the `ORDER BY` clause in a `SELECT` statement. The `ORDER BY` clause has to be *before* the `LIMIT` clause.

---

And you've got a simple problem in the php syntax, there's an extra double quote at the beginning of the last line of code you posted.